# kotlin spring @WebMvcTest is slow

Tags: spring, kotlin, junit

I'm using @WebMVcTest for the integration test in kotlin, spring.

The speed of the test varies a lot for each method, but I don't know the exact cause.

Each test method code is as follows.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `test1`() {
        // given
        val folderList = mutableListOf(
            Folder.FolderListResponse(1L, "emoji1", "child1"),
            Folder.FolderListResponse(2L, "emoji2", "child2")
        )
        every { folderService.findFolderChildList(any()) } returns folderList

        // when
        val resultAction = util.getResultAction("/api/v1/folder/1/children", mockMvc)

        // then
        resultAction
            .andExpect(status().isOk)
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].folderId").value(1L))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].emoji").value("emoji1"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name").value("child1"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].folderId").value(2L))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].emoji").value("emoji2"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].name").value("child2"))
    }


    @Test
    fun `test2`() {
        // given
        val info1 = AccountDto.FolderBelongAccountInfo(1, "info1", "images")
        val info2 = AccountDto.FolderBelongAccountInfo(2, "info2", "images")
        val expected = AccountDto.FolderBelongAccountListDto(mutableListOf(info1, info2))
        every { folderService.getAccountListAtRootFolder(any()) } returns expected

        // when
        val resultAction = util.getResultAction("/api/v1/folder/belong/1", mockMvc)

        // then
        resultAction
            .andExpect(status().isOk)
    }


    fun getResultAction(uri: String, mockMvc: MockMvc): ResultActions {
        return mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(uri)
                .header("AccessToken", "token")
                .header("RefreshToken", "retoken")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .characterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
        )
    }
```

test1 takes 31 ms, while test2 takes 800 ms.

```kotlin
// test1 result

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/v1/folder
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", AccessToken:"token", RefreshToken:"retoken", Accept:"application/json"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.yapp.web2.domain.folder.controller.FolderController
           Method = com.yapp.web2.domain.folder.controller.FolderController#findAll(HttpServletRequest)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []


// test2 result

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/v1/folder/belong/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", AccessToken:"token", RefreshToken:"retoken", Accept:"application/json"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.yapp.web2.domain.folder.controller.FolderController
           Method = com.yapp.web2.domain.folder.controller.FolderController#getAccountList(long)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"list":[{"id":1,"name":"info1","profileImage":"images"},{"id":2,"name":"info2","profileImage":"images"}]}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

The performance of test2 is slower than test1 every time, so what is the cause?